# playing audio with MPMoviePlayerViewController

Tags: audio, mpmovieplayercontroller

Reference iOS TabController app...

Apple docs state that the AVAudioPlayer class does not provide support for streaming audio based on HTTP URL's.  AVAudioPlayer plays only music embedded in the iApp with a file:// as a url.

Given that, I do use MPMoviePlayerViewController to play these web stored audio/mp3 files which it can handle.

This definitely works. I start out with a UIView with the lyrics for the song. At the very bottom of this UIView is a "Play" button. The user taps this button and the audio/mp3 plays; however, the audio/QuickTime (( Q )) graphic comes to the foreground and the lyrics disappear and will stay away until the user taps "Done". What I want to happen is that the audio/mp3 is played in the background, with the lyrics staying in front.

BTW, I really don't need for the "Done" button to be seen because the user can stop the audio by simply selecting another Tab.

Obviously this going to the background for the AV file makes sense because the MPMoviePlayerController object is designed to play video and the video ought to come to the front. It is consistent in that the audio also goes to the background .. except I need a way to defeat the audio/QuickTime (( Q )) graphic coming to the front.

I did insert code to determine if it was an audio file (mp3), versus a video file (mp4).  So far so good ... and then if it was an audio file, within my actual playing segment, I have:

```
if ( NSClassFromString(@"MPMoviePlayerViewController") )
{
    if (!isAudioFile)
    {
        [senderViewController
         presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:moviePlayerViewController_];
    }
}

[moviePlayerController_ play];
```

It actually works, that is, I actually hear the mp3 in the background, with the lyrics in front and the audio/QuickTime (( Q )) graphic does not show ...

**BUT, what does happen is horrible, that is, the "Done" button shows over the lyrics** I talked about with some sort of unknown ??? letters there.

Comment: You should remove the solution from the question and then add it as an answer (and then accept it if it solved your problem).

Comment: Thanks, but I'm afraid that the "powers on high" definitely do not like my approach to combining a question with the correct answer.  They dislike it so much that I am "blacklisted" .. I am barred from asking any question at all.  Never heard of a "blacklisted" former University professor before!  When I taught Computer Information Systems that is the approach I took and by gum it worked well for the students.

Comment: What I meant is that you should edit your question to not have the answer in it and then choose "Answer Your Question" at the bottom to post the solution as an answer. This is preferred because it matches the general format of the rest of the site, with questions separate from answers. If you are unable to do that for some reason I can do it for you.

Comment: I can because I have done it that way.  Nevertheless, this is moot since I can no longer ask questions.  It began when I could not figure out multiple steps for submitting to the app store. Stackoverflow decided that this question and my *very mild* rant warranted my expulsion. I went to iphonedevsdk.com. What a different tone .. not condescending, not 'I'm going to sit on you if you don't comply'. But, very helpful with precise answers and multiple 'don't panic, John; it will come together; just stick with it'.  It *has* come together and now I can't believe I was so dumb about the app store.

Comment: Don't worry about it; I fixed it for you.

Answer (score 0):

The following answer is taken from an edit to the question:

```
if ( NSClassFromString(@"MPMoviePlayerViewController") )
{
    if (!isAudioFile)
    {
        [senderViewController
         presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:moviePlayerViewController_];
    }
    else
    {
        [moviePlayerController_ setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleNone];
    }
}
```

FWIW, I really don't need a "Done" button because as soon as I go to another tab, either new music or a video, the music initially playing stops and the new AV file starts.